# DynamoDB query times out in mocha test

Tags: node.js, dynamo-local

I am running a pair of Docker containers, one with DynamoDB local running and the other running Nodejs. They are linked and I can confirm the link is working by running :

```
$ aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url=http://dynamodb:8000
```

I don't think this is part of the problem, I'm just listing it here for completeness.

However, I can't get the following test script in mocha to work. The test just times out:

> Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.

Here's the test script:

```
'use strict';

var expect = require('chai').expect;
var aws = require('aws-sdk');

aws.config.update({ accessKeyId: 'fakeAccessKey', secretAccessKey: 'fakeSecretAccessKey', region: 'fakeRegion',  });
var db = new aws.DynamoDB({ params: { endpoint: 'http://dynamodb:8000' }});

describe('queue-handler', function() {
    it('should connect to dynamodb and list tables', function(done) {
        console.log("Check for tables...");
        db.listTables({}, function(err, data) {
            console.log("list tables returned.");
            if(err)
                console.log("Error listTables: " + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
            else
                console.log("listTables: " + JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

I can see "Check for tables..." logged, but not "list tables returned.".

Comment: No experience with this myself, but from [the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#constructor_details) it looks like `endpoint` should be a direct property of the `options` object passed to the constructor: `new aws.DynamoDB({ endpoint : ... })`

Comment: @robertklep that was it! If you'll post that as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#constructor_details) suggests that `endpoint` should be a "direct" property to the options object (and not nested in `params`):

```
var db = new aws.DynamoDB({ endpoint: 'http://dynamodb:8000' });
```